# The type or namespace name 'Highsoft' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Im using Visual Studio 2017 and have installed the Highsoft.Highcharts nuget package version 5.0.6352.17134. This is an Asp.net MVC5 web project.

Im trying to create a dashboard with multiple charts in it. I have the main dashboard page with a model that contains all the chart info. I then send each chart's info to a partial view to create the chart.

The problem im running into is that the @html helpers are not found. I have included the @using statement and i can see that Highsoft.Web.Mvc is referenced in the project.

The error im receiving is "The type or namespace name 'Highsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" I cant for the life of me figure out the issue.

Below is the code for the Charts Partial View

```
@model DashboardDemo.Models.DashboardChart


@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

@(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
    new Highcharts
    {
        Title = new Title
        {
            Text = "Monthly Average Temperature",
            X = -20
        },
        Subtitle = new Subtitle
        {
            Text = "Source: WorldClimate.com",
            X = -20
        },
        XAxis = new List<XAxis>
        {
            new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new List<string> { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" },

            }
        },
        YAxis = new List<YAxis>
        {
            new YAxis
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle
                {
                    Text = "Temperature (°C)"
                },
                PlotLines = new List<YAxisPlotLines>
                {
                        new YAxisPlotLines
                    {
                        Value = 0,
                        Width = 1,
                        Color = "#808080"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Tooltip = new Tooltip
        {
            ValueSuffix = "°C"
        },
        Legend = new Legend
        {
            Layout = LegendLayout.Vertical,
            Align = LegendAlign.Right,
            VerticalAlign = LegendVerticalAlign.Middle,
            BorderWidth = 0
        },
        Series = new List<Series>
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Name = "Tokyo",
                Data = @ViewData["tokyoData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Name = "NY",
                Data = @ViewData["nyData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Name = "Berlin",
                Data = @ViewData["berlinData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Name = "London",
                Data = @ViewData["londonData"] as List<LineSeriesData>
            }
        }
    }
        , "chart")
)
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio 2017? Sometimes, similar issue happen with me also in VS 2017.

Comment: Yes, i did restart VS. it did take away the red marks under the Highcharts name however, when i run it i still get an error page, object reference not set to an instance of an object and its pointing to line 5:  @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(

Comment: Just updated to the latest version by allowing beta builds.. same issue occurs.

Comment: Is it .NET Core? If so, the html will be invisible. The wrapper currently works for .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your nuget package manager and uninstall the Highsoft.Web.Mvc and instead install the Highsoft.Highcharts, rebuild app and you should be good.